# Convert any data type to NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
cell.textField.text = [contact valueForKey:formCell.variableName];
```

The valueForKey which i get is of unknown type, it can be NSNumber, int, float, NSString..

I want to convert the value to NSString.

using NSString stringWithFormat, should specify format specifier, the type of object is known at run time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `valueForKey:` will never return `int` or `float`. Instead, it will wrap them into `NSNumber`s. Details [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/DataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002171-184696).
2. Therefore, you can use `"%@"` to represent them in `stringWithFormat:`.
3. You can also use `description` method of `NSObject` like this: `[[contact valueForKey:formCell.variableName] description]`.

Comment: Interesting about NSNumber. Final code in my case `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict valueForKey:@"key"]]`

Answer (score 4):

There’s a `-description` message that works on any object descended from `NSObject`:

```
cell.textField.text = [[contact valueForKey:…] description];
```

Using the `%@` format specifier calls `-description` in the background, so that the two are mostly equivalent, only the direct `-description` call is shorter and probably more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

you can try use the description method:

```
cell.textField.text = [[contact valueForKey:formCell.variableName] description];
```

usually, it's implemented as string, representing value of the object

Answer (score 1):

description: is a method that you can call on any NSObject, that should return an NSString* of description text.

> http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html

There are some cases where it'll even be called automagically for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
cell.textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[contact valueForKey:formCell.variableName]];
```

Comment: You can also use description method of NSObject like this: [[contact valueForKey:formCell.variableName] description].